# Using sprintf with columnheader as an argument in title

Tags: printf, gnuplot, columnheader

I'm using gnuplot v4.6 patchlevel 6 to create a stacked graph of time series data. When I attempt to use the `sprintf()` function in the `plot` statement after the `title` command, gnuplot reports:

```
"stacked.plot", line 81: undefined function: columnheader
```

I've modelled my plot after this article https://newspaint.wordpress.com/2013/09/11/creating-a-filled-stack-graph-in-gnuplot/.

The data looks like:

```
epoch read_count write_count
1450760479 4933.0 3598.0
1450760779 8049.0 2161.0
1450761079 6099.0 2458.0
1450761379 3670.0 2349.0
1450761679 4130.0 2336.0
1450761979 2415.0 3222.0
```

And my plot command looks like:

```
j=3
plot \
  for [i=2:j:1] \
    TARGET using 1:(sum [col=i:j] column(col)) \
      title sprintf("%s - %s",HOST,columnheader(i)) \
      with filledcurves x1
```

If I do nothing other than removing the `sprintf()` function, gnuplot happily completes the task without error.

```
j=3
plot \
  for [i=2:j:1] \
    TARGET using 1:(sum [col=i:j] column(col)) \
      title columnheader(i) \
      with filledcurves x1
```

Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/34262075/2604213

Comment: Thank you for the incredibly quick response!

Comment: consider upvoting answers that have helped solve your problem. Good luck to all.